# Do I need JavaScript/jQuery for this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If you look at my updated [code pen](https://codepen.io/_Loot_/pen/ExgaXLL) I want the box-shadow for

```
#menu ul li ul {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999 !important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 3px solid #171314;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #171314;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 2px 0px #0F0B0C; 
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 2px 0px #0F0B0C;
}
```

to display the box-shadow only when the drop-down is active / Clicked, and to display no box-shadow when it's not active.
is there a way to fix this with CSS or anybody know javascript to fix my problem?

I tried `#menu ul li ul:active`

Comment: Know that it's possible to create a 'fiddle/codepen' example at this site too. At the text area edit, click the toolbar icon that has `<>`.  (I'm not a big fan of codepen)

Comment: I tried that but now it says it mostly code now

Comment: Here’s your orginal question: [Do I need JavaScript for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65171264/do-i-need-javascript-for-this). Don’t repost questions. Edit your original one.

Comment: You'll probably need to modify your current Javascript a little bit to add a class `.open` when it opens, and remove the class `.open` when it closes. Then, you can attach your box-shadow to that class.

Answer (score 0):

You already have written the javascript in the code, just need to modify it a little bit. Instead of hiding the sub-menu li(s) you need to hide and show sub-menu ul. Also you need to toggle the boxShadow class on sub-menu ul to display the box shadow. Review the snippet below:

```js
var nav = $("#menu > ul > li");
nav.find("ul.menus").hide();
nav.click(function () {
  nav.not(this).find("ul.menus").hide();
  $(this).find("ul.menus").slideToggle();
  $(this).find("ul.menus").toggleClass("boxShadow");
});

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("open").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("close").style.display = "flex";
  $("#menu ul").slideToggle();
  $("#menu ul").toggleClass("boxShadow");
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("open").style.display = "flex";
  document.getElementById("close").style.display = "none";
  $("#menu ul").slideToggle();
}

$(function () {
  nav.mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find("ul.menus").slideUp();
  });
});

$(window).on("resize load", function () {
  var win = $(this);
  if (win.width() <= 973) {
    $("#close").attr("style", "display:none;");
    $("#open").attr("style", "display:flex;");
  } else {
    $("#close").attr("style", "display:flex;");
    $("#menu ul").attr("style", "display:flex;");
  }
});
```

```css
.col {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #171314;
  border-top: 3px solid #171314;
  background-color: #0f0b0c;
}
/* Navigation
--------------------------------------------- */
#menu {
  position: relative;
}
#menu ul,
#menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#menu li {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: "Press Start 2P", cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #7906b2;
  border-left: 3px solid #0f0b0c;
  border-right: 3px solid #0f0b0c;
}

#menu ul li:hover a {
  background: #221e1f;
  color: #950dd9;
  border-left: 3px solid #171314;
  border-right: 3px solid #171314;
}

#menu input {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  width: 45px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu label {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: none;
  width: 35px;
  line-height: 2.8125em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#menu ul li ul {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999 !important;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  border-right: 3px solid #171314;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #171314;
  display:none;
}
.boxShadow{
   box-shadow: 3px 2px 2px 0px #0f0b0c;
}
#menu ul li ul li {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Fredoka One", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell,
    "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  text-transform: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

#menu ul li ul li a {
  color: #908a8a !important;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  line-height: 35px;
  background: #221e1f;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#menu a.nav-a-drop::after {
  font-family: "Hideout-Font";
  content: "\0041";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 30px;
}

#menu a.nav-a-drop:hover::after,
#menu ul li:hover a.nav-a-drop::after {
  font-family: "Hideout-Font";
  content: "\0041";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 30px;
}

#menu ul li ul li a:hover {
  background: #333333;
  color: #bab2b2 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka+One&family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<nav id="menu" class="col">
  <label>
    <i id="open" onclick="openNav()" class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    <i id="close" onclick="closeNav()" class="fas fa-times"></i>
  </label>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#' class='nav-a' title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class='nav-a-drop' href='#!' title="Custom Content">Custom Content</a>
      <ul class='menus'>
        <li><a href='#' title="Drop Menu1">Drop Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' title="Drop Menu2">Drop Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' title="Drop Menu3">Drop Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' title="Drop Menu1">Drop Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' title="Drop Menu2">Drop Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' title="Drop Menu3">Drop Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' title="Drop Menu1">Drop Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' title="Drop Menu2">Drop Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' title="Drop Menu3">Drop Menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class='nav-a-drop' href='#!' title="Build Videos">Build Videos</a>
      <ul class='menus'>
        <li><a href='#' title="Speed Builds">Speed Builds</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' title="Stopmotion">Stopmotion</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#' class='nav-a' title="Build Pics">Build Pics</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```